# Who wrote शुभम करोति कल्याणम?

Tags: shloka, prayer

There is a very famous prayer, in Maharashtra (and maybe in other parts of India too) which goes like below,

```
शुभं करोति कल्याणम आरोग्यं धनसंपदा ।
शत्रुबुद्धि विनाशाय दीपज्योति नमोsस्तुते ।
```

Usually, around evening time, either the kids or elders in the family sings this prayer. The full text/lyrics of this prayer can be found [here](https://mantramaya.com/shubham-karoti-kalyanam/lyrics-marathi.php)

My Question is who wrote this famous prayer?